# Firebase Cloud Function - How can I solve this error: ECONNRESET

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

This is my code

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const axios = require('axios');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().functions);

exports.sendNotifications = functions
.region('europe-west1')
.pubsub.schedule('every day 04:00').onRun(async context => {

    axios.get('http://niksimoni.pythonanywhere.com/api/pulizie_domani')
    .then(listOfStreets => {
        const streets = listOfStreets.data.strade;
        const promises = [];
        for (const street of streets) {
            const p = axios.get('http://niksimoni.pythonanywhere.com/api/data_pulizie?indirizzo=' + street)
            .then(listOfHours => {
                const ora = listOfHours.data.ora;
                var topic = street.split(" ").join("-");
                var message = {
                    data: {
                        title: street,
                        subtitle: 'Pulizia domani alle ' + ora,
                    },
                    topic: topic
                };
                admin.messaging().send(message)
                .then((response) => {
                    // Response is a message ID string.
                    console.log('Successfully sent message:', response);
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.log('Error sending message:', error);
                });
            })
            promises.push(p);
        }
        return Promise.all(promises);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
  });
```

I tried replacing axios with request but it did not solve the issue, no matter what I change I always get this error: 'Error while making request: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established. Error code: ECONNRESET'
I tried to learn how to handle promises, and I thought I understood it, but maybe I am wrong.
Any help would be appreciate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always return the promise inside cloud functions:

```
return axios.get('http://niksimoni.pythonanywhere.com/api/pulizie_domani')
```

And this too:

```
return admin.messaging().send(message)
```

Otherwise, cloud functions will kill the executing code abruptly. You might want to do the same for your catch block too. You can read more about it here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions

Comment: do I have to keep this return statement: return Promise.all(promises);?

Comment: Yes. Even if you miss one return statement in the promise chain, that stack of the code is not guaranteed to execute in cloud functions.

Comment: unfortunately I got the same error even with those changes...

Comment: Return the response:
 return admin.messaging().send(message)
                .then((response) => {
                    return response;
                })
and see if the response is printed as an array in output by executing it from "TESTING" (https://console.cloud.google.com/functions/details/us-central1/<funtion>?project=<project>&tab=testing)

Comment: Also, add your new code in the question, so that I can take a look at it.

Comment: Testing it on my terminal I encountered a different error: malformed topic name, and I had just to replace a few characters that firebase does not like and it was working like magic. I still did not receive the notification (I subscribed on my phone to a topic that is part of the list of topics which should have received a notification, but I am sure that this is a problem that I can handle). Thank you really much!